# SwiftUI matchedGeometryEffect "Multiple inserted views in matched geometry group Pair warning" when View embedded in Button

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swiftui

I would like to achieve a slide animation of an underline moving from one tab to another when the user selects a different one
[image]

I'm using matchedGeometryEffect as follows:

```
       HStack(spacing: 15) {
            ForEach(categories, id: \.self) { category in
                let isSelected = selectedVal == category
                Button {
                    withAnimation {
                        selectedVal = category
                    }
                } label: {
                    VStack(spacing: 4) {
                        Text(category)
                            .frame(width: 100)
                        if isSelected {
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                                .frame(width: 50, height: 2)
                                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "Category", in: animation, isSource: isSelected)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

This approach works with the warning of `Multiple inserted views in matched geometry group Pair<String, ID>(first: "Category", second: SwiftUI.Namespace.ID(id: 10)) have isSource: true, results are undefined.`

When I extract the `RoundedRectangle` from the `Button`the warning disappears:

```
      HStack(spacing: 15) {
            ForEach(categories, id: \.self) { category in
                let isSelected = selectedVal == category
                VStack(spacing: 4) {
                    Button(category) {
                        withAnimation {
                            selectedVal = category
                        }
                    }
                    
                    if isSelected {
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                            .frame(width: 50, height: 2)
                            .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "Category", in: animation, isSource: isSelected)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I suspect this is something to do with the `Button` not being removed from the view hierarchy in the first solution and therefore still holding a reference to the `RoundedRectangle` which confuses matchedGeometry as you can't have the source view "visible" but I would have though `isSource` being set to the selected state would have solved this. Is there an explanation as to why I'm getting the warning in the first scenario?

Comment: As for me it looks like a SwiftUI bug.

Comment: I've found setting the animation duration to a faster time can help avoid collisions where a user may press a button at an inopportune time during tweening. Why it needs to crash the program instead of just giving up is beyond me.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you can set matchedgeometryeffect with same namespace only one view at once. so that SwiftUI can figure out which object to be animated. and here are you setting geometry effect all three view with same namespace so swiftUI can not figure out how to animate and layout all the view.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    enum Tab: String {
        case one
        case two
        case three
    }
    
    @State private var selected: Tab = .one
    @Namespace private var tabNameSpace
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            HStack(spacing: 32) {
                
                ZStack {
                    if selected == .one {
                        Color.red
                            .frame(width: 100, height: 50)
                            .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "namespace", in: tabNameSpace)
                    }
                    
                    Text(Tab.one.rawValue)
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 50)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            withAnimation(.spring()) {
                                selected = .one
                            }
                        }
                }
                
                ZStack {
                    if selected == .two {
                        Color.red
                            .frame(width: 100, height: 50)
                            .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "namespace", in: tabNameSpace)
                    }
                    
                    Text(Tab.two.rawValue)
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 50)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            withAnimation(.spring()) {
                                selected = .two
                            }
                        }
                }
                
                ZStack {
                    if selected == .three {
                        Color.red
                            .frame(width: 100, height: 50)
                            .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "namespace", in: tabNameSpace)
                    }
                    
                    Text(Tab.three.rawValue)
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 50)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            withAnimation(.spring()) {
                                selected = .three
                            }
                        }
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```